# nested fetch for a response in a service-worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I'm new to service-worker. I'm following a training of **Mobile Web Specialist** given by Udacity and I'm using google-chrome for that.
I want to fetch for a response from the network, and if it returns 404 as a status I fetch for another response from the network as well.
This is a code to fetch from the network only once. This code works perfectly:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 404) {
        return new Response("Whoops, not found");
      }
      return response;
    }).catch(function() {
      return new Response("Uh oh, that totally failed!");
    })
  );
});
```

I did some updates on this code by throwing an error after getting `response.status === 404` and manage it the same way in a `try/catch`. The updated code is below:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
 try {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 404) {
        throw (Error);
      }
      return response;
    }).catch(function() {
      return new Response("Uh oh, that totally failed!");
    })
  );
 } catch (Error) {
   event.respondWith(
    fetch('/imgs/dr-evil.gif').then(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 404) {
        return new Response('couldn\'t fetch twice');
      }
      return response;
    }).catch(function() {
      return new Response("Uh oh, that totally failed twice!");
    })
  );
 }
});
```

I know there is a better way to do a nested fetch using the service-worker, but I want to know what I did wrong here.

Comment: I don't know service worker very well, but do you need to do your `fetch(event.request)` block outside of the `event.respondWith`? I'm wondering if it can't ever leave that respondWidh method after it's entered (and never hitting the outside catch)

Comment: Oh, yeah, reading it more closely your first fetch promise chain is always resolving to a response, even the catch handler. The outer catch is dead code.

Comment: Good question @dgeare. I don't know how to do the block inside the first  `if (response.status === 404)` since `fetch` is a promise and I can't do the `return` statement inside of it. I didn't get very well your second comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not run this so it's possible it needs some adjustments, but try something like this. The problem with your current code is that the first fetch promise chain always resolves to a Response. Either in the first `then` or in the first `catch`, where you return a response of `"Uh oh, that totally failed!"`. The `event.respondWith` takes that response and happily goes along it's way.

The outer `try/catch` exists in a synchronous space, where as the fetch kicks off an asynchronous chain, so there will be no way for your code to reach the outer catch since it's not in the execution context for the fetch.

If the compatability is the same for both service worker and async/await (I don't know) you might want to take a look at that as it would be a much friendlier way to structure your code.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 404) {
                throw (Error);
            }
            return response;
        }).catch(function() {
            return fetch('/imgs/dr-evil.gif').then(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 404) {
                    throw (Error);
                }
                return response;
            })
        }).catch(function() {
            return new Response("Uh oh, that totally failed twice!");
        })
    ); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the problem. I did some adjustments, and it workes. This is the final code: self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) { event.respondWith( fetch(event.request).then(function(response) { return fetch('/imgs/dr-evil.gif').then(function(response) { if (response.status === 404) { throw (Error); } return response; }); }).catch(function() { if (response.status === 404) { throw (Error); } return response; }).catch(function() { return new Response("Uh oh, that totally failed twice!"); }) ) });